# MediaStore Audio not showing songs from google play music

Tags: android, mediastore

I have the following code to get all the music from a device.  my device has music downloaded via [Google's Play Music app](https://play.google.com/about/music/).. but these files don't show up.. any idea why..

here is my code:

```
String[] musicProjParams = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, 
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST};
    //String[] cont = { "audio/mpeg" };
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    musicCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, musicProjParams,
            selection,
            null, 
            "UPPER(" +MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " )ASC");
    mAdapter = new DRPMusicFromPhoneAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, musicCursor,
            new String[] { "_id, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },albumArtMap);
    _searchResultsView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: I suggest you first check if you have any records selected by adding int count = musicCursor.getCount(); Log.i(TAG,"selected "+ count);
If you have a selection, the issue lies in displaying.

Comment: @erk, I'm havng the same issue, can you please tell me if you find any solution to this problem.